# Stanford Wrangler ideal, but imposes limits, what are other options?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, database, sql, r

Stanford Wrangle tool is quite amazing, and I solved a giant problem with it, but it limits me to very small size. My file is about 500MB, and it allows me to process less than 1MB, the remaining data is just curled up in one cell. After 15th row (tried on several files) it simply stops

http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/app/

I have 50k of following data, 1 record

```
Osnovni podaci
PREDUZETNIK
OLIVA
Registarski broj : 10000015
Matični broj : 02386135
Broj promjene : 1
Puni naziv : OLIVA
Šifra djelatnosti : 5610
Naziv djelatnosti : Djelatnosti restorana i pokretnih ugostiteljskih objekta
Adresa sjedišta : STOLIV BB
Mjesto sjedišta : KOTOR
Adresa prijema službene pošte : STOLIV BB
Mjesto prijema službene pošte : KOTOR
Datum registracije : 28.06.2002
Datum promjene : 28.06.2002
Status : Aktivan
Lica u društvu
Ime :   DEJAN
Prezime :    BAJO
JMBG :   2910971230014
```

And with function wrap at line I got it to following table CSV table

> Osnovni podaci, PREDUZETNIK, OLIVA, Registarski broj : 10000015,
>   Matični broj : 02386135, Broj promjene : 1, Puni naziv : OLIVA, Šifra
>   djelatnosti : 5610, Naziv djelatnosti : Djelatnosti restorana i
>   pokretnih ugostiteljskih objekta, Adresa sjedišta : STOLIV BB, Mjesto
>   sjedišta : KOTOR, Adresa prijema službene pošte : STOLIV BB, Mjesto
>   prijema službene pošte : KOTOR, Datum registracije : 28.06.2002, Datum
>   promjene : 28.06.2002, Status : Aktivan, Lica u društvu, Ime :    DEJAN,
>   Prezime :  BAJO, JMBG :    2910971230014

How else can this be done? It transposed and wrapped data at first line of each record ("Osnovni podaci").

Basically I am utilising function transpose which wraps at specific line, and I do not know how could I use this function in other tools like excel, r, python or sql? I am familiar with them.

Help?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want done so we don't need to look up this wrangler tool to understand. You want to wrap csv files? Convert xls to csv? I assume you are using windows?

Comment: Above is 1 record, and I have 50k of those. File is in txt, and I want it in csv, wraped and transposed at each beginning of record. Wrangler  wraps/transposes data at specific line.